# How to process PHP Array with JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, variables

Hopefully some can help me figure out following issue..

I perform following query:

```
$key = "privatehashere";
$query = file_get_contents("https://privateurlhere/?key_id=" . $key . "&paramshere");
```

According to official documentation, I know the output is a JSON, which is encoded. So I decode it and transform to PHP array:

```
$result = json_decode($query, true);
```

At this point, when I display the output with **`<pre>`** tag and **`print_r`** function, I get:

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [data] => Array
        (
            [grp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [number] => 24384
                            [desc] => ENTITY-2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [number] => 46590
                            [desc] => ENTITY-1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I need, is to save the end values to variables, so I can work with them further. So the result should be ideally:

```
$number_0 = "24384"
$desc_0 = "ENTITY-2"
$number_1 = "46590"
$desc_1 = "ENTITY-1"
```

Thanks for any suggestions / hints.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: These variables can hardly be called "ideal"

Comment: Why put them in scalar variables? They are in an array leave them there and use the values by addressing the array i.e. `if ( $result['status'] == 'ok' ){` If you give the variable `$result` a more meaningful name it will beome self documenting!

Comment: @GeraldSchneider My bad. Other guys already told me what's wrong  about them. Anyway, try to be more specific next time ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have to work with the JSON output as it is; unfortunatelly I can't modify the original values.

Comment: Where am I saying you should modify anything. Once you do the `json_decode()` you have an array that is all yours. To process, to love and cherish, to amend or not amend. Duplicating it all out into new scalar variables just doubles you memory requirement and increases your runtime. If you prefer to work with objects then leave the `,true` off the `json_decode()` and I bet you would get a nice object to deal with

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach($result['data']['grp'] as $item)
{
    echo 'Number '.$item['number'];
    echo '<br/>desc '.$item['desc'];
}
```

You can also store them directly into variables.

```
$number_0 = $result['data']['grp'][0]['number'];
$desc_0 = $result['data']['grp'][0]['desc'];
$number_1 = $result['data']['grp'][1]['number'];
$desc_1 = $result['data']['grp'][1]['desc'];
```

**Note**: In `PHP` you cannot start variable name with numeric. like you did here `$0_number`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the note about variable name. I'm beginner in PHP and I didn't think about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying this method is good practice, it is however a direct answer to your question:

```
$number_0 = $result['data']['grp'][0]['number'];
$desc_0 = $result['data']['grp'][0]['desc'];
$number_1 = $result['data']['grp'][1]['number'];
$desc_1 = $result['data']['grp'][1]['desc'];
```

If you want to dynamically assign variables from the array, you can do it like this:

```
foreach( $result['data']['grp'] as $k => $v )
{
    ${'number_'.$k} = $v['number'];
    ${'desc_'.$k} = $v['desc'];
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`, a php variable can't start with a number

Comment: Thanks. Guess I wanted to be a little bit too quick. Updated it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard As mentioned in my answer, I do not think this is best practice. I just wanted to answer OP's question as closely as possible. There's many ways to get data from an array and there are even more ways to store the retrieved data. Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you retrieved your array.
now formation of your required variables.
you cannot initiate your variable with numeric Value. instead we form it like this `$subKey_mainKey` eg. `$number_0;`

```
$getDetails[0]  = array("number"=>24384, "desc"=>"ENTITY-2");
$getDetails[1]  = array("number"=>46590, "desc"=>"ENTITY-1");
foreach($getDetails as $indKey=>$indArray) {
    foreach($indArray as $indNKey=>$indNVal) {
        $createVar  = $indNKey."_".$indKey;
        $$createVar = $indNVal;
    }
}
echo $number_0;
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but big thanks about the variable names. As I mentioned above, I'm beginner in PHP and I didn't think about this.

Comment: as per my understanding, i answered my best. so if you brief me some more about your requirement, it would be helpful for me to give you the best solution. Thanks & cheers.